# Something strange with date input in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, input

I'm trying to set default date as max date in date input when input value changed and the value is null or undefined.First I select today as value,it is normal.Then I cleared date(click fork of like 'x'),value turned into default value('1970-01-01').Then I select today as value again,In My js code has check value is undefined,so the value was set to default value('1970-01-01').I wonder why I can not select today as value,What happened?I tested in chrome browser.

html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
          <input type="date" max="{{today}}" ng-model="myDate.date" ng-change="change()">
      </div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**js code:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myDate = {
    date:null
}
$scope.today = '2016-03-14';
$scope.change = function(){
    if(!$scope.myDate.date){
        $scope.myDate.date = new Date('1970-01-01');
    }
}
}]);
```

[refer picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DafPz.jpg)

http://plnkr.co/edit/UKtn8FbvsczbFtn44Vuq?p=preview

Comment: Please add plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't recommend using Chrome's built-in datepicker, as using your approach makes the input box completely unusable in FF.

Concerning your issue:

This is what the output date looks like to me when selecting `2016-03-14` as input: `2016-03-13T23:00:00.000Z` (Offset is due to my timeszone I assume).

Now let's reset the input box by pressing the "x": `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`.

If I now try and select the `2016-03-14` again it won't work, it defaults back to `1970-01-01`, due to the date plus my timezone now exceeding the `max` allowed input value.

Adding the timezone to `new Date('1970-01-01')` should fix the issue (using `new Date('1970-01-01T23:00:00.000Z')` worked for me and allowed me to select `2016-03-14`).

Comment: Thank you for your help.This help me a lot.I live in Timezone 8.I using new Date('1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z') to fix the issue.At the same time I need to change the default value to new Date('1969-12-31T16:00:00.000Z').@chrissatchell

Comment: @Ao.Zhang Will it still work though if users from other timezones input their date? That's the question